# How to change multiple entries with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

How to dynamically change other entries in real time?

When I type `value1`, I want to instantly change `value2` and `value3` and then the same with the other fields.

I know I should use useEffect but when I think of how to do this on several different inputs simultaneously I am in doubt.

I try this ...

```
export default function Performance() {
  const myVariableProp = 20;
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState('');
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState('');
  const [value3, setValue3] = useState('');

  // on change text value1 dynamically change other values
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue2(value1 * 4);
    setValue3(value1 / 4);
  }, [myVariableProp, value1]);

  // on change text value2 dynamically change other values
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue1(4.2 / 32500);
    setValue3(value1 / myVariableProp);
  }, [myVariableProp, value1]);

  // on change text value3 dynamically change other values
  useEffect(() => {
    const math = myVariableProp * value2;
    setValue1(math);
    setValue2(value1 * myVariableProp * 4.2);
  }, [myVariableProp, value2, value1]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Performance</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={value1}
        onChangeText={setValue1}
        style={{backgroundColor: '#e3e3e3'}}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={value2}
        onChangeText={setValue2}
        style={{backgroundColor: '#f3e3e3'}}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={value3}
        onChangeText={setValue3}
        style={{backgroundColor: '#c3e3e3'}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `myVariableProp` isn't variable, it's a `const` initiialized to a literal value...?

Comment: That's it, I tried to simulate as a navigation parameter just for this example, sorry.

Comment: Those calculations are really odd. The first one is straightforward enough, but your second two changes `value1` based on changes to `value1`, which will loop infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not in this way

```
const setValue1Handler =(newValue1) => {
    setValue1(newValue1);
    setValue2(newValue1 * 4);
    setValue3(newValue1 / 4);
}

<TextInput
   value={value1}
   onChangeText={setValue1Handler}
   style={{backgroundColor: '#e3e3e3'}}
 />
```

And the same for the other functions :)

*For questions feel free to comment*

Comment: This is not gonna work. When you do `setValue1` and then immediately call `setValue2(value1 * 4);`, `value1` will not be updated yet, and as a result old value of `value1` will be used.

Comment: check again, we are using the value from the parameter of the function :) not the state [maybe some better names would be needed :v--]

Comment: This is a very generic answer, but it's the direction I'd suggest the OP go in. It would be a much better answer if it were more specific to the OP's question, but the calculations in the OP's question are quite odd, making it difficult to do that. One thing I would definitely do, though, is change that parameter name so people aren't confused like @Clarity was. Shadowing the state variable like that is a very bad idea.

Comment: Right, my bad, that's why variable shadowing is a bad idea ;)

Comment: parameters changed

Comment: I tried Arrow Function before but it didn't work so I tried UseEffect. The problem was the input expected a value of type text and I passed number, I added in InputText `value={\`${quantityEntry}\`}` and Arrow Function worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

The function that is passed as the first parameter of useEffect, can be executed when some variables change. These variables are passed inside an array as the second parameter of useEffect. For example:

```
 // on change text value1 dynamically change other values
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue2(value1 * 4);
    setValue3(value1 / 4);
  }, [value1]);

  // on change text value2 dynamically change other values
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue1(4.2 / 32500);
    setValue3(value1 / myVariableProp);
  }, [value2]);

  //etc...
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect